# Angular - Form validation without form tag

Tags: html, angular, forms

I'm trying to finalise a register form. I've to do it without using the form tag.

I've this registerform:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="center col-xs-8 col-xs-offset-2">

        <p class="h5 text-center mb-4">{{ 'Signup' | translate }}</p>

        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="email">{{ 'SignupEmail' | translate }}</label>
                <input type="text" [(ngModel)]="user.email" class="form-control" [ngClass]="{ 'is-invalid': submitted && f.email.errors }" />
                <div *ngIf="submitted && f.email.errors" class="invalid-feedback">
                    <div *ngIf="f.email.errors.required">Email is required</div>
                    <div *ngIf="f.email.errors.email">Email must be a valid email address</div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="username">{{ 'SignupUsername' | translate }}</label>
                <input type="text"  [(ngModel)]="user.name" class="form-control" [ngClass]="{ 'is-invalid': submitted && f.email.errors }" />
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="password">{{ 'SignupPassword' | translate }}</label>
                <input type="password"  [(ngModel)]="user.password" class="form-control" [ngClass]="{ 'is-invalid': submitted && f.email.errors }" />
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="birth">{{ 'SignupBirth' | translate }}</label>
                <input type="date"  [(ngModel)]="user.dateNaissance" class="form-control" [ngClass]="{ 'is-invalid': submitted && f.email.errors }" />
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <button [disabled]="loading" class="btn btn-info" (click)="onSubmit()" >{{ 'SignupSubmit' | translate }}</button>
                <img *ngIf="loading" src="data:image/gif;base64,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" />
                <div class="text-center">
                  {{ 'SignupAccount1' | translate }} <a routerLink="/login">{{ 'SignupAccount2' | translate }}</a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

The problem, is that the mail and the other input are always required even if i put a correct address mail in the input. And i don't get why...

Here is the **register.component.ts**

```
import {Component, OnInit} from '@angular/core';
import {FormGroup, FormBuilder, Validators} from '@angular/forms';
import {first} from 'rxjs/operators';
import {Router} from '@angular/router';
import {AlertService} from '../services/alert.service';
import {UserService} from '../services/user.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-register',
  templateUrl: './register.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./register.component.sass']
})
export class RegisterComponent implements OnInit {

  registerForm: FormGroup;
  loading = false;
  submitted = false;
  user: any;


  constructor(private fb: FormBuilder, private router: Router, private userService: UserService, private alertService: AlertService) {

  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.registerForm = this.fb.group({
      username: ['', Validators.required],
      //gender: ['', Validators.required],
      birth: ['', Validators.required],
      email: ['', [Validators.required, Validators.email]],
      password: ['', [Validators.required, Validators.minLength(8)]]
    });

    this.user = new Object();

  }

  click(ev) {
    console.log(ev.target.defaultValue);
  }

  // convenience getter for easy access to form fields
  get f() {return this.registerForm.controls;}

  onSubmit() {
    this.submitted = true;

    // stop here if form is invalid
    if (this.registerForm.invalid) {
      window.alert("Informations invalides");
      return;
    }

    this.loading = true;
    this.userService.register(this.registerForm.value)
      .pipe(first())
      .subscribe(
      data => {
        this.alertService.success('Registration successful', true);
        this.router.navigate(['/login']);
      },
      error => {
        this.alertService.error(error);
        this.loading = false;
      });
  }

}
```

Can you help me validate this form (but without adding the form tag)...

Thank you !

Comment: Since your inputs are not registered the form controls... whatever you type in fields doesn't populate the form so of course it will be invalid, since the form fields are empty ;)

Comment: @AJT_82 What am I missing ? name="email" ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You had used reactive form, So use `[formGroup]` in div and inside that div use `formControlName` to achieve validation.

Here i have created one reactive form demo with validation and without `form` tag.

[Stackblitz Demo without Form Tag](https://stackblitz.com/edit/email-phone-validation-reactive)