# How to validate ion-datetime tag in Ionic 4 app?

Tags: javascript, angular, ionic-framework

I'm building Ionic 4 app with Angular 7. Why **required** doesn't work in **ion-datetime** tag? Below is my code:

```
<ion-item>
        <ion-label>In Time</ion-label>
        <ion-datetime displayFormat="HH:mm" [(ngModel)]="todo.myInTime" required></ion-datetime>
    </ion-item>
    <ion-item>
        <ion-label>Out Time</ion-label>
        <ion-datetime displayFormat="HH:mm" [(ngModel)]="todo.myOutTime" required></ion-datetime>
    </ion-item>
 <ion-button expand="full" (click)="saveTodo()">Save</ion-button>
```

**Update**

I am adding my Component.ts file.

```
async saveTodo(){
    const loading = await this.loadingController.create({
      message: 'Saving.. Please Wait!'
    });

    await loading.present();

    if(this.todoId)
    {
      this.todoService.updateTodo(this.todo, this.todoId).then(() => {
        loading.dismiss();
        this.nav.goBack();
      })

    }else{
      this.todoService.addTodo(this.todo).then(() => {
        loading.dismiss();
        // this.nav.navigateBack('home');
        this.router.navigate(['/home']);
      })
    }
  }
```

Comment: add your component.ts code as well.

Comment: @SudarshanaDayananda Mate, I have updated my post with component.ts code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use angular form controls to show validations. You can do it as below.

**HTML**

```
<form [formGroup]="myGroup">
  <ion-item>
    <ion-label>Start Time</ion-label>
    <ion-datetime formControlName="datetime" [(ngModel)]="fData. datetime" displayFormat="HH:mm"></ion-datetime>
  </ion-item>
</form>
```

**TS**

```
export class ExamplePage {

  myGroup: FormGroup;
  fData = { "datetime": "" };

  constructor() {

    this.myGroup = new FormGroup({
      datetime: new FormControl('', [Validators.required]),
    });
  }
}
```

Hope this will helpful and see my [stackblitz demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ionic-vc5fmy?file=pages%2Fhome%2Fhome.ts)

Comment: Mate, this is absolutely correct. Happy with your code. The way you have shown is the custom way. But, isn't it possible without using Form tag and just using the required attribute.

Comment: You can do it. but I think using form tag is easy. go through this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52184517/angular-form-validation-without-form-tag